# Does UNLOAD command removes or deletes data from redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I want to copy table data from redshift to S3; but keep original data in redshift. I know there is UNLOAD command for that purpose. But I am not sure if it deletes/removes data from original table. Does somebody have solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unload does not delete or remove data from the original table.  See the explicit truncate in the [COPY reload example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com./redshift/latest/dg/t_Reloading_unload_files.html)